# Keep the sites-available/enabled structure when compiling Nginx

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, configuration

I am using `nginx` on `ubuntu` which by default has the `sites-available/enabled` directory structure similar to `Apache` to store the sites configuration files. I have compiled `nginx` (because I need a third party module) using the below configuration:

```
./configure \
    --prefix=/opt/nginx/version \
    --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log \
    --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log \
    --pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid \
    --with-http_ssl_module \
    --user=nginx \
    --group=nginx \
    --add-module=...
```

Nginx is working fine, but right now I need to configure all my sites in `/opt/nginx/version/conf/nginx.conf` which isn't as maintainable as with the `sites-available/enabled` directory structure whereby I can create 1 file per site and decide which ones are enabled with symlinks.

I had a look at the [install options](http://wiki.nginx.org/InstallOptions) but all I see is `--conf-path` to specify the path to `nginx.conf`.

**Is there a way to reuse the `sites-available/enabled` directory structure with a compiled nginx?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you look inside the default Ubuntu /etc/nginx/nginx.conf you ought to find the following line.

```
http {
    ...
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

That is what you need to get the sites-enabled magic happen.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't `nginx` installed on any machine, but I guess that this is handled the same way as in Apache, where the main configuration file just includes all files located in `/etc/apache/sites-enabled`. These files are in turn just symlinks to files in `/etc/apache/sites-available` and these links are either manually mananged or with the help of the `a2enable` script family.

It should be very easy to recreate a similar structure with your self-compiled `nginx`.